# Modin read_csv issue

Tags: pandas, ray, modin

I'm attempting to read a csv file using modin and it results in the following error. this issue seems to happen on all dataframe operations:

> RayWorkerError: The worker died unexpectedly while executing this
>   task.

Python 3.7.3
Pandas 0.24.2
Modin 0.5.4
Ray 0.7.1

```
import modin.pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

frame_data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2**10, 2**8))
pd.DataFrame(frame_data).to_csv('frame_data.csv')
pd.read_csv('frame_data.csv').head()
```

Comment: This issue is tracked in the ray project as a "stability blocker" as of 07-August-2019 in the following location : https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5316

Comment: The comment at https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5316#issuecomment-519367386 suggests that doing `pip uninstall typing` may fix the issue. There appears to be a bug with the `typing` module in Python 3.7.

Comment: Yes, `pip uninstall typing` does work fine. 
This raises the question of how well integration tested before releasing in PyPI. Uninstalling packages like this in a production environment without considering the dependencies for other packages dosent seem ideal.

Comment: It's definitely not ideal. I *think* that it's an issue with the `typing` module that needs to be fixed. But maybe there's something that can be done on the Ray side to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

OP confirmed that the reason for the failure was the presence of the `typing` package, and that uninstalling `typing` fished the issue. That was a temporary fix for the issue tracked on Ray [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5316#issuecomment-519367386). That issue was [closed](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5316#issuecomment-538104635) once Modin fixed the order of imports for the `typing` library. The latest version of Modin (0.12.0) should not have that problem.